# How do I pass a variable used in a function to a variable in another function in C?

Tags: c, function

I'm making a small and simple game in C as a project for college.
In the game, there's a function in which the player will buy troops of different types for his army. Then, during the execution of the other function, the player will position the troops bought in the game scenario, but the function "needs to know" how many troops and of which type the player bought.

So basically, what I'm asking is how do I pass the value of a variable used in a function to be used in another one.

Comment: Return a value from one function and use it as a parameter to another function. This will be covered in any basic C tutorial or book.

Comment: I can't use the return of the function.

Comment: Keep this information on the higher level - for example global.

Comment: Don't do global variables. If you can't use the return value, just pass a pointer into the function and mutate it. But if you're doing this sort of thing, you might need to redesign. If you're keeping a lot of state, then consider returning a struct that represents an object. Since you haven't shown a [mcve], it's hard to say what your situation is based on a short description alone.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
typedef enum
{
    PLAYER_COMMAND_BUY,
    PLAYER_COMMAND_GET,
    PALYER_COMMAND_SET,
}PLAYER_COMMAND_t;

int manage_player(PLAYER_COMMAND_t command, unsigned *data)
{
    static unsigned nplayers;
    int result = 0; //OK

    switch(command)
    {
        case PLAYER_COMMAND_BUY:
            /* do something to buy players */
            /* set nplayers */
            break;
        case PLAYER_COMMAND_GET:
            *data = nplayers;
            /* do something to buy players */
            break;
        case PALYER_COMMAND_SET:
            /* do something to buy players */
            nplayers = data;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code needs to work a lot with common data in different functions, you could put this data in a embedded database  (sqlite for example) that will be part of you executable.